# How to find form.has_errors OR form.errors and enable the error in the first place

Tags: django

I have several related questions and post under one topic for clarity's sake.

```
# Django/django_bookmarks/urls.py    
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', main_page),
    (r'^user/(\w+)/$', user_page),
    (r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
)    

# login.html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Django Bookmarks - User Login</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>User Login</h1>
    {% if form.errors %}
    <p>Your username and password didn't match.
      Please try again.</p>
    {% endif %}
    <form method="post" action=".">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <p><label for="id_username">Username:</label>
    {{ form.username }}</p>
      <p><label for="id_password">Password:</label>
    {{ form.password }}</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" />
      <input type="submit" value="login" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Based on the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847196780), the **login.html** uses `form.has_errors` instead of `form.errors`. However, the `form.has_errors` doesn't print any warning message even if I enter a wrong user/password. After some investigation, I change it to `form.errors` and it works for me.

Question 1> Which one should be used `form.errors` or `form.has_errors`?

Question 2> If `form.has_errors` doesn't work, why django doesn't complain in the first place. The book was written for Django 1.0 and I am using Django 1.3. Is that the reason?

Question 3> How to check which attributes the form has? I have tried the following and it doesn't give the information I needed.

```
python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import django.contrib.auth.views
>>> dir(django.contrib.auth.views)
['AuthenticationForm', 'HttpResponseRedirect', 'PasswordChangeForm', 'PasswordResetForm', 'QueryDict', 'REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME', 'RequestContext', 'SetPasswordForm', 'User', '_', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'auth_login', 'auth_logout', 'base36_to_int', 'csrf_protect', 'default_token_generator', 'get_current_site', 'login', 'login_required', 'logout', 'logout_then_login', 'never_cache', 'password_change', 'password_change_done', 'password_reset', 'password_reset_complete', 'password_reset_confirm', 'password_reset_done', 'redirect_to_login', 'render_to_response', 'reverse', 'settings', 'urlparse']
>>>
>>> dir(django.contrib.auth.views.login)
['__call__', '__class__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__globals__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__name__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'func_closure', 'func_code', 'func_defaults', 'func_dict', 'func_doc', 'func_globals', 'func_name']
```

Question 4> When the following statement is needed?

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`form.has_errors` is not documented in the [forms api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/). I did a quick grep of the source code, and I could not find it in either Django 1.3 or my svn checkout of the 1.0.X branch. It seems that it's a mistake in the book you are using.

Checking [`form.errors`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors) in your template is fine.

If you tried to access `form.has_errors` in the view, you would get an `AttributeError`. However Django does not complain when try to access an variable that does not exist in the template, so `{{ form.has_errors }}` fails silently. See the docs on [template variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#variables) for more info.

To introspect the attributes on the form, use `dir` on the form object, not the view.

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.views import AuthenticationForm
>>> dir(AuthenticationForm)
```

However I recommend you explore the [form api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/) docs instead.

The csrf token is required when you are using Django's [cross site request forgery protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/).

Comment: Do you know why django doesn't report errors when we use form.has_errors? -thx

Comment: As far as I am aware, django forms do not have a `has_errors` method or attribute. It's not in the documentation or the source code as far as I can see. I assume it's a mistake in the book.

Comment: I think `is_valid` is only useful after a POST request.

Comment: is_valid is false if the form has not yet been submitted at least once. (I was trying to use this in JS to determine if the form had errors, but if it can't be distinguished from not having been submitted then it is useless for that).

Comment: @KatharineOsborne yes, `is_valid` is always False if the form has not been submitted (you can use `is_bound` to check that). The `is_valid` method is useful in the view, but I can't think of a common case where it would be useful in the template so I've removed it from the answer. Just use `form.errors` as my answer said.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using a django for loop to find the specific fields that had errors (the form is structured as an accordion, so I needed to expose the panels that had errors, when there were errors): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields

Answer (score 3):

> Question 1> Which one should be used `form.errors` or `form.has_errors`?

`form.has_errors` works for example in a view but not in a template ([django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.has_error)).

In the template you should check for errors with `{% if form.errors %} your code goes here {%endif %}`

> Question 2> If form.has_errors doesn't work, why django doesn't complain in the first place. The book was written for Django 1.0 and I am using Django 1.3. Is that the reason?

All `DoesNotExist` exceptions fail silently. See [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups) -> *Note that `django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist`, which is the base class for all Django database API `DoesNotExist` exceptions, has `silent_variable_failure = True`. **So if you’re using Django templates with Django model objects, any `DoesNotExist` exception will fail silently.***

> Question 4> When the following statement is needed? `{% csrf_token %}`

If I'm not mistaken a `csrf_token` is always needed when you want to post a form ([csrf docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/)).

I usually render errors like this:

```
{% if form.errors %}
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible col-12 mx-1" role="alert">
    <div id="form_errors">
    {% for key, value in form.errors.items %}
        <span class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ key }}:{{ value }}
        </span>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

`form.has_errors` is just a boolean (`True/False`). It's a convenience method for testing if a form has errors or not (obviously).

`form.errors`, on the other hand, is the actual array of errors.

Comment: Then, why if I use form.has_errors, the warning message cannot be seen?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I stumbled upon it trying to find a similar answer, so I figured I'd share what I found. Seems like questions 2-4 have been answered adequately; I'll just add some info to question 1.

I'm using Django 3.0.

In the [Django Forms API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.has_error), I didn't find `form.has_errors`, but there *is* a `form.has_error()` (note that error is singular). I don't think it would be useful to the OP's use case.

## 1. Simple Fix

In OP's case, you could simply replace

```
{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match.
  Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}
```

with

```
{{ form.errors }}
```

assuming you're raising a validation error in your form (Django documentation on validating forms is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#using-forms-to-validate-data) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/)). OP is using Django's Authentication framework, which will raise the validation error OP is looking for when the form is submitted without needing any extra tweaking.

Using `{{ form.errors }}` will also ensure that in the future, if you choose to add more errors, you won't need to hard-code those into the template.

Conveniently, if you don't have any errors, `{{ form.errors }}` won't add any extra html to your page when it's rendered. Django fails silently for most template variables by default.

This won't be especially pretty; @P.Maino and @Toby Speight's code for rendering will give you something much more visually appealing, but it requires Bootstrap. Bootstrap claims to be "the world’s most popular front-end open source toolkit"; you can [download or connect via CDN to version 4.5 here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/download/).

## 2. Slightly More Complicated

If you're manually rendering fields in your template, you can manually render errors specific to those fields as well. In this case, *don't* use `{{ form.errors }}`; split up your error messages by rendering non-form errors using `{{ form.non_form_errors }}` somewhere appropriate (I usually choose the top of the form or just under the page's navbar when it has one). Then, for each separate field, use `{{ form.<field_name>.errors }}` to render errors for each field. [Documentation is here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually); OP's template would look something like this:

```
<!-- login.html -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Django Bookmarks - User Login</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>User Login</h1>
    {{ form.non_form_errors }} <!-- Show errors not tied to a field -->
    <form method="post" action=".">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.username.errors }} <!-- Show errors for the username field -->
      <p>
        <label for="id_username">Username:</label>
        {{ form.username }}
      </p>
      {{ form.password.errors }} <!-- Show errors for the password field -->
      <p>
        <label for="id_password">Password:</label>
        {{ form.password }}
      </p>
      <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" />
      <input type="submit" value="login" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Again, probably not especially pretty, but probably more obvious to the user than `{{ form.errors }}`. This method also ensures you don't need to hard-code error messages into the template; you will, however, need to add the `{{ form.<field_name>.errors }}` tag to every new input you want to be able to display errors for.

You can dress the `{{ form.<field_name>.errors }}` similar to @P.Maino and @Toby Speight's answer like this:

```
{% for error in  form.<field_name>.errors %} <!-- Insert your field name here -->
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible col-12 mx-1" role="alert">
    {{ error }}
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
{% endfor %}
```

Just replace `{{ form.<field_name>.errors }}` with the above instead.

## PS

There are methods to set CSS classes for form rows based on whether they have errors. See [Styling required or erroneous form rows](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#styling-required-or-erroneous-form-rows).